# What's the complexity of sum i=0 -> n (n_i*i))

Tags: big-o

This is a test I failed because I thought this complexity would be O(n), but it appears i'm wrong and it's O(n^2). Why not O(n)?

[image: problem]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is this problem taken from? Do we know anything about a_i other than what's provided here?

Comment: Question is not complexity but Big O limit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation. To answer question note `min(a_i)*sum(1, 2, ..., n)< f(n)  < max(a_i)* sum(1, 2, ..., n)`

Comment: This problem is from my exam. All questions are independent so we don't know anything else about a_i

Comment: The thing is, the first thing I thought when i saw the question was an array of a_i of n elemts so i thought this could be a for loop that for i in range n that just does a[i]*i. Why is that incorrect? The complexity would be just O(n) because it just does this n times, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the question does not ask what is the time complexity of a function *calculating* `f(n)`, but rather the complexity of the function `f(n)` itself. you can think about `f(n)` as being the time complexity of some other algorithm if you are more comfortable talking about *time* complexity.
This is indeed `O(n^2)`, when the sequence `a_i` is bounded by a constant and each `a_i` is at least 1.
By the assumption, for all `i`, `a_i <= c` for some constant `c`.
Hence, `a_1*1+...+a_n*n <= c * (1 + 2 + ... + n)`. Now we need to show that `1 + 2 +... + n = O(n^2)` to complete the proof.

```
1 + 2 + ... + n <= n + n + ... + n = n * n = n ^ 2
```

and

```
1 + 2 + ... + n >= n / 2 + (n / 2 + 1) + ... + n >= (n / 2) * (n / 2) = n^2/4
```

So the complexity is actually `Theta(n^2)`.
Note that if `a_i` was **not** constant, e.g., `a_i = i` then the result is not correct.
in that case, `f(n) = 1^2 + 2^2 + ... + n^2` and you can show easily (using the same method as before) that `f(n) = Omega(n^3)`, which means it's not `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 0):

Preface, not super great with complexity-theory but I'll take a stab.

I think what is confusing is that its not a time complexity problem, but rather the functions complexity.

So for easy part `i` just goes up to n ie. 1,2,3 ...n , then for a<sub>i</sub> all entries must be above 0 meaning that `a` could be something like this 2,5,1... for n times. If you multiply them together n*n = O(n<sup>2</sup>).

The best case would be if `a` is 1,1,1 which drop the complexity down to O(n) but the average case will be n so you get squared.

Comment: This is what I was initially thinking, but you can't bound the sum at O(n^2) unless you know what the individual terms are. For example, what if a_n = n^1000 for each n?

Comment: @templatetypedef you are misunderstanding big o notation and the function. a_i are constants and question is how magnitude of f changes as n tends to infinity. Noting that `min(a_i)*sum(1, 2, ..., n)< f(n) < max(a_i)* sum(1, 2, ..., n)` and the answer drops out

Comment: Suppose that a_i = log n for each index i. In that case, the sum would be Theta(n log n). In other words, if the terms of the sequence are defined in terms of n, then the asymptotic growth of the sum will come out to different values.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's mentioned that a[i] is O(n), it's definitely O(n)

Comment: I'm not sure whether this is correct. I think the question is asking about the value of the sum given by f(n), not the time required to evaluate f(n).

Comment: That makes sense totally

Answer (score -1):

Here an another try to achieve O(n*n) if **sum** should be returned as result.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<=n; i++){
   for(int j = 0; j<=n; j++){
        if(i == j){
            sum += A[i] * j;
        }
    }
return sum;
```

Comment: I know, O(n) is the most likely, but however , this should give O(n*n) .